# Download and extract .tar.gz file with PHP cURL and return to client as string doesn't work

Tags: php, http, curl, gzip

I try to download a .tar.gz file via PHP cURL, extract it and return the file's content as string to the client.

When I try via terminal it works:

```
curl "https://domain.com/filename.tar.gz?what=ever&fu=bar" | tar -xz
```

Trying via PHP cURL doesn't work (where responseUrl comes from the client app):

```
$_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($_curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $_POST['responseUrl'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
));
$_responseFile = curl_exec($_curl);
curl_close($_curl);

echo file_get_contents($_responseFile);
```

The return I get to the client Angular2 app is:

```
Response {
    _body: "",
    headers: Headers,
    ok: true,
    status: 200,
    statusText: "Ok",
    type: 2,
    url: "http://test.local/api/getResponse.php",
    __proto__: Object
}
```

What's wrong with my script? Any help appreciated!

Comment: The urls you are showing are completely different. One being a `tar.gz` file, the other a `.php` response, so of course you'll get differing results...

Comment: No, I call the PHP script from a client app and parse the URL of the file to download as $_POST['responseUrl']. But that was a bit unclear. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 2):

I can help - How To Download & Extract Zip Archives in PHP

Hope it will work for the  .tar.gz file.

PHP has the Zip Archive Extension. You can see the [php manual for installing ZipArchive Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.setup.php). The usage of ZipArchive extension is very easy.

**Download**

For downloading, we will use cURL. First we create a blank zip file, download the zip file from server and put it’s contents to the blank zip file we created.

```
$url = "http://example.com/pathtozipfile.zip";
$zipFile = "folder/zipfile.zip"; // Local Zip File Path
$zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");
// Get The Zip File From Server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$page) {
echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

cURL will get the Zip archive file from url mentioned in the variable $url. The $zipFile variable contain the local path of the file were we’re going to save the Zip archive file.

**Extract (Unzip)**

For extracting as we mentioned before, we will use the PHP Zip Archive Extension.
We’ll make the class variable, open the Zip archive file and extract it :

```
/* Open the Zip file */
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$extractPath = "path_to_extract";
if($zip->open($zipFile) != "true"){
echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";
} 
/* Extract Zip File */
$zip->extractTo($extractPath);
$zip->close();
```

The extract path should be mentioned in the $extractPath variable. If any of the files exists, it will be overwritten or merged.